# Как сконфигурировать Swagger Spring (non-boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, swagger

Моя конфигурация выглядит так:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.docs.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.docs.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
//P.S. <swagger.docs.version>2.9.2</swagger.docs.version>
```

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {ControllerPackageMarker.class, MappersPackageMarker.class})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource("classpath:media.upload.properties")
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${upload.path}")
    private String path;

    @Value("${max.file.size}")
    private long maxFileSize;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver());
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(maxFileSize);
        return multipartResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations(isWindows ? "file:///" + path : "file://" + path);
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Согласно документации, бина и зависимости в pom достаточно, но, когда я перехожу по ссылке `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` ничего не показывает((

В секьюрити конфиге я указала `antMathers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll();`

Вот, что выходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скрина, на страниу меня пускает, но страница совершенно пустая

(Все контроллеры на месте)

**UPD**: `/v2/api-docs` работают, отдают json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не работают следующие урлы(404):

```
app_root/v2/swagger-ui/
app_root/swagger-ui/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтош)

разрешить урл `/swagger-ui.html` было недостаточно. Вот, что решило мой вопрос:

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**");
    }
```

Это я переопределила в SpringSecurity конфиге и все заработало

Answer (score 2):

У меня в одном из проектов `/swagger-ui.html` не работал из-за зависимости

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Если никак не получается починить, то можно скачать билд `swagger ui` и загрузить его как статичные файлы (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases/tag/v3.47.1 директория `dist`)

Но вообще рекомендую посмотреть в сторону `openApi`